# Passing labeled values to toggle checkbox component

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a toggle component with two labelled values. I am using this component in another component.

what is the best way to pass the value to my child component on the toggle value change?

this is the `HTML` and `CSS` below. Thank you for helping me with toggle component.

Also i need to set a default value of the toggle, in below example ABC, how do i set the default value.

My question is as i am using my toggle-checkbox selector to display the toggle button. on change of toggle value from A to B, what is the best `Angular` way to pass the value of toggle on change to the calling component?

Here is the stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nprhys?embed=1&file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Below is the template and `CSS` for toggle component:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="td-wb-checkbox__input"
          id="toggle" class="checkBox" />
        <label for="toggle" class='buttonWarpper'>
          <div>left</div>
          <div>right</div>
        </label>

        .buttonWarpper {
          position: relative;
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
          width: fit-content;
          border: 3px solid #f02d1f;
          border-radius: 20px;
          background: #f02d1f;
          color: #f02d1f;
          cursor: pointer;
        }

        .buttonWarpper::before {
          content: '';
          position: absolute;
          width: 50%;
          height: 100%;
          left: 0%;
          border-radius: 20px;
          background: white;
          transition: all 0.3s;
        }

        .checkBox:checked+.buttonWarpper::before {
          left: 50%;
        }

        .buttonWarpper div {
          padding: 10px;
          text-align: center;
          z-index: 1;
        }

        .checkBox {
          display: none;
        }

        .checkBox:checked+.buttonWarpper div:first-child {
          color: white;
          transition: color 0.5s;
        }

        .checkBox:checked+.buttonWarpper div:last-child {
          color: #f02d1f;
          transition: color 0.5s;
        }

        .checkBox+.buttonWarpper div:first-child {
          color: #f02d1f;
          transition: color 0.3s;
        }

        .checkBox+.buttonWarpper div:last-child {
          color: white;
          transition: color 0.5s;
        }
```

Comment: please share the minimal reproducible code also refine your question with more details, if possible provide a stackblitz for quick debugging!

Comment: Hi Naren, thank you for your reply. Adding the stackblitz.                                                        https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nprhys?embed=1&file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts